# Amazon MWS GetReport Invalid Date Range

Tags: php, curl, amazon-mws

I keep getting an invalid date range response from my request. I am not sure what is wrong. I have all the parameters and a valid ReportID.

```
$params = array(
    'AWSAccessKeyId' => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    'Action' => "GetReport",
    'SellerId' => MERCHANT_ID,
    'SignatureMethod' => "HmacSHA256",
    'SignatureVersion' => "2",
    'Timestamp' => $timestamp,
    'Version'=> "2009-01-01",
    'Marketplace' => MARKETPLACE_ID,
    'ReportId' => $reportID
    );

// Sort the URL parameters
$url_parts = array();
foreach(array_keys($params) as $key)
    $url_parts[] = $key . "=" . str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($params[$key]));

sort($url_parts);

// Construct the string to sign
$url_string = implode("&", $url_parts);
$string_to_sign = "GET\nmws.amazonservices.com\n/Reports/2009-01-01\n" . $url_string;

// Sign the request
$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, TRUE);

// Base64 encode the signature and make it URL safe
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

$url = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Reports/2009-01-01" . '?' . $url_string . "&Signature=" . $signature;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($response);
```

The output I get back is Invalid Date Range

Answer (score 0):

Does it work through Amazon's [scratchpad](https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html)?  I just tried a GetReport operation and it came back just fine.  Of course no date range is needed because you're trying to get back a specific report by id.  I usually go to the scratchpad as a quick and easy way to get info from MWS.

My POST looks like this:

[image]

Comment: yes it works on amazon scratch pad which is why i am so confused and having such trouble

Comment: Actually, I get Invalid Date Range error on ScratchPad. I am not sure why this error is coming up. All the input is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well after contacting Amazon this is what is came down to. When I requested the report using the RequestReport Action I supplied an invalid Date Range. So the report itself return Invalid Date Range as the content of the report.